# There's a way to deselect the selected item in VB.Net Combobox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm adding 12 Combobox to a TabBox by code and selecting index 0, also by code, to all of them when the Form load.

All the Comboboxes has a collection added at design time

Visually I get all the texts selected with a blue background, like when you select some text in a text processor program.

I don't want that I just want that all of them gets is default background color.

I'm getting this

[image: Blue Select]

And I want this

[image: White Select]

Here's the code

```
Private Sub ZoneTypesLoad()
    Dim X As Integer = 4
    Dim Y As Integer = 0
    X = 4
    Y = 10
    For xZona As Integer = 1 To 12
        Dim MyZoneTypePrg As New TiposDeZonas
        Dim Ubicacion As Point
        Ubicacion.X = X
        Ubicacion.Y = Y
        With MyZoneTypePrg
            .Name = "ModZoneTypePrg" & xZona.ToString
            .GPB1.Text = "Zona " & xZona.ToString
            .GPB1.ForeColor = Color.Blue
            .ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
            .Parent = Me
            .Location = Ubicacion
            .Visible = True
            .TabIndex = xZona
        End With
        ZoneTypesTabPrg.Controls.Add(MyZoneTypePrg)
        Y += 60
        If xZona = 6 Then
            X += 190
            Y = 10
        End If
    Next

    ZoneTypesTabPrg.Focus()

End Sub
```

Comment: This is because the combobox has focus. Where do you want the focus to go at this point instead? Focus is always _somewhere_; If you don't like it there, you can't just unset it. You have to decide where it should be instead.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn To the main Tab. The strange is all of them get blue at same time. Why not just one of them?

Comment: *I'm adding 12 Combobox to a TabBox by code* (do you mean TabControl?) -> *All the Comboboxes has a collection added at design time*: you should probably post the code that reproduces this behavior and clarify those two sentences.

Comment: As soon as you finish adding the comboboxes, you want to add a line of code that looks something like `mainTab.Focus()`. If the controls are part of this main tab, given they all have the same index property, you may also need to be more specific about those indexes.

Comment: @Jimi Yes, I'm talking about TabControls. Code added.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I tried but didn't work, maybe because they are inside a User control.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: @CaiusJard There's two images in the post, both are from the App. From what part do you need a screenshot?

Comment: The whole screen perhaps; interested to know the surrounding context too, moreso than what a single focused combo looks like

Comment: Why do you have `.Parent = Me`? What is `ZoneTypesTabPrg`? Not a TabControl, since you cannot add Controls that are not TabPages to it, not a TabPage, since you cannot `Focus()` it. -- Do you have code in `SelectedIndexChanged`? -- BTW, you should use a TableLayoutPanel to layout your UCs. Child Controls of the UC should not be `public` fields.

Comment: Do you want these combos to actually be combos (i.e. you can type random text into them that is not a list item) - or do you just want them to show items from the list? (DropDownStyle is not, by default, DropDownList)

Comment: @CaiusJard The Main Form has a TabPage->TabPage->TabPage->UserControl. I just a list, I don't want that they be editable, they contains fixed options. I'm adding user controls that have a ComboBox inside a GroupBox.

Comment: @Jimi The Main Form has a TabPage->TabPage->TabPage->UserControl. I'm adding by code user controls that have a ComboBox inside a GroupBox.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. A Form has nested TabPages? What are you focusing? What are you adding these Control to? A GroupBox? You cannot `Focus()` a GroupBox either.

Comment: @Jimi Yes is one TabPage inside another 3 times because the App has way to many options and some options must be grouped together. The whole App is to configure and program many types of external devices that make different functions; the current section is part of a burglar alarm system. I'm just adding the UserControls by code, not the tab pages. The Focus in ton the Tab at the end, or should.

Comment: You cannot use `Focus()` on a TabPage, it's not focusable (it's a Panel, `Focus()` is not available). It's not clear at all what you have there, how you nested TabPages or what this: `ZoneTypesTabPrg.Focus()` actually is. Unless you wrote code here that is not actually what you have there. Or where a GroupBox comes into play and so on.

Comment: @Jimi I think is complete logical that a TabPage can't be focusable but the method exist, I don't wrote it manually, I picked up from the options after I wrote ZoneTypesTabPrg. Is available, at least in VB.2010

Comment: So, how you doing on that screenshot of your running UI and designer? Also, open the Document Outline window in the designer and screenshot that